# How to add breadcrum in custom page?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I have created one custom page. Also created breadcrumb service which perfectly work for admin page but doesn't work for custom page.Even I have checked my custom theme setting where breadcrumb visibility is set true.

Snippet of code

```
company.services.yml
services:
  company.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\company\Breadcrumb\CompanyBreadcrumbBuilder
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 100 }


CompanyBreadcrumbBuilder.php

namespace Drupal\company\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

class CompanyBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface{
    /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
    public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $attributes) {
        $parameters = $attributes->getParameters()->all();

        return true;
    }

    /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
    public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
        $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));
        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Article', '<front>'));
        return $breadcrumb;
    }
}
```

m missing something like setting?

Note: I m using bootstrap as base theme.

Comment: You still have to ensure the block is being output in a region or you are injecting the breadcrumb as a twig variable.

Comment: YEP what ^^^ Kevin said make sure you place the block !

Comment: Thanks. Breadcrumb block was disable under block list. Once it was enable it was working perfectly.